# How to create toggle element only using html5

Tags: html

I go to the TestDome to test my CSS and HTML skill. There is one question that I can't answer. The question is to write a toggle element by html5 without using javascript and css. So, how can I write it

Comment: SO is here to help you with what you've tried. Can you please edit your post with your attempted code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: You do need either JS or CSS to toggle something unless you have two files or a server process

Comment: though this is not a proper way to ask question here, still I'm helping you with a clue, you can use `checkbox`, please update the question as it's not meeting the SO guidelines

Answer (score -1):

The following structure will do the trick:

```
<details>
  <summary>Epcot Center</summary>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</details>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think they mean a toggle switch. You can easily use a input checkbox like so `<input type="checkbox" />`. You can then style the switch.